# Building Flux/React application without NodeJs EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, reactjs, flux

Hi I'm trying to build a Flux/React application with a go-lang back-end. I have been following a tutorial I found [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-simple-shopping-cart-with-react-js-and-flux). But I have a problem when building the store. In the tutorial something like this is used to create a base for the store.

```
var ProductStore = _.extend({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {...});
```

The problem I have is I do not have access to the EventEmitter library which I understand is a Nodejs lib? Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: You can also look at third-party libraries like [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2) or any other pub-sub style lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use NodeJS libraries in the browser! Take a look at [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

First some code:

```
// index.js
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var ProductStore = function() {};
ProductStore.prototype = new EventEmitter;
```

Then you run browserify on it:

```
browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

Also worth a look is [WebPack](http://webpack.github.io/) which does the same thing. (but has some additional features)

Comment: Will browserify integrate well with requirejs? And would I need node to use browserify. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson No, browserify does not integrate with requirejs. They are two different module systems and are designed differently. If you want to use requirejs with npm packages, I'd recommend you look at Webpack.

Comment: @Caleb do you prefer requirejs or browserify?

Comment: You do need node. I tend to include scripts manually (though I've used brunch or gulp too). You can use browserify to generate a bundle of just the lib you need, then include it like a regular file. See the "standalone" option here: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage. With this approach you only need node once, after that it's just regular javascript.

Comment: I ended up using eventemitter2.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are using the flux implementation given by Facebook (https://github.com/facebook/flux), you can actually **extends their FluxStore class** which comes with a build in eventEmitter.

The only thing if you want to do that is you must use es6 classes (and use babel to transpile to es5).

The good thing about it is that you don't have to implement the `addListener` `removeListener` and `emitChange` methods, and that's very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) :)

With this solution, your stores will end up looking like that :

```
var FluxStore = require("flux/utils").Store,
    thing;

class ThingStore extends FluxStore {
    getThing() { 
        return thing;
    }

    __onDispatch(payload) {
       //your code
    }
}
```